# Can I post this puzzle? I'm not even sure if it is a puzzle but surely looks like one!

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

If you are a fan of *The Green Team*, or technology in general, you might know that the Pascal GTX 1080 is just around the corner...

For more information, visit:

- [This article on HEXUS](http://hexus.net/tech/news/graphics/92528-nvidia-teasing-pascal-launch-order-10-puzzle-website/)
- [The official NVidia 'teaser' site](http://orderof10.com/humanityshallbeenlightened) - *Note that the site has multiple pages; don't just get carried away by the home page*.

The site, itself seems to be a puzzle. If not, it is surely *made* to *look* like a puzzle. So, would it be even *okay* to post this here? I mean, we've got a community of excellent minds. I am sure they will certainly be able to extract some info out of it. And if you visit the site, you'll find it's not just tech... there's stuff about astronomy, mathematics, etc. as well.

So, would it be fine if I posted this, or would I get down-voted by unicorns?

> Who knows? I might even get hammered right here... :)

Jokes apart, should I, or should I not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the rule is that puzzles (or any questions on any StackExchange site) should be self-contained:  All the information required to solve the puzzle should be available in the post.  (Of course, for trivia-related puzzles and whatnot, googling for general information (*not* a specific URL) is expected.)

It sounds like this puzzle is contained in a number of different pages of a website, which would make it hard to replicate in Puzzling.SE post.

Therefore, it is probably not appropriate for the site.

**As an alternative**, you could always post the URL in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair) and collaborate with people on it that way.

Comment: thought so... who cares 'bout nvidia :)